# Electrical wires worked with a melting connector but when I cut them and tested by twisting them together it wont work

Tags: electrical, wiring, connector, ground

So, like the title said I had a 3 wire connector plug which I assumed had wires grounding in it which was causing it to overheat and melt, when i clipped the wires and twisted them together to see if the grounding problem was in the connecter none of the wires work anymore, wires were aluminum to copper.  Any ideas on why it might not work?

Comment: are you sure you connected them correctly and did not mix them up?

Comment: What do you mean by grounding? Do you mean that they were shorting to ground.  What is more likely is that the connector has a poor connection causing a voltage drop and therfore the connection got hot.  Did you clean the wires before twisting them together?